# GeoServer keeps redirecting to http://

Tags: geoserver, jetty, nginx

My GeoServer keeps redirecting the (browser) client to HTTP while it should stay in HTTPS.

Running GeoServer 2.24.1 or 2.24.2 with Jetty or Tomcat and a nginx reverse proxy with a SSL certificate in front of it.

### Example browser log for a single visit to https://example.com/geoserver/

https://example.com/geoserver/ does a `302 Redirect` to `/geoserver/index.html`

https://example.com/geoserver/index.html then serves HTML with a JS redirect `window.location.replace("web/")`

https://example.com/geoserver/web/ then does a `302 Redirect` to `http://example.com/geoserver/web/?1` (notice the `http` instead of `https` or a protocol agnostic `//geoserver/...`)

### The nginx configuration should be fine:

```
        location /geoserver {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345/geoserver;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

### Nothing helpful in the GeoServer logs:

I enabled GEOSERVER DEVELOPER LOGGING with Enable Request Logging, Log Request Bodies and Log Request Headers but saw nothing related to http/https or redirection.

### Nothing helpful in the Jetty logs:

By adding

`Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG"`
to the systemd `geoserver.service` file I got lots of debugging output visible via `journalctl -u geoserver -f`.

For example my request:

```
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: GET //example.com/geoserver/web/?0 HTTP/1.0
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Host: example.com
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Real-IP: 123.123.123.123
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Forwarded-For: 123.123.123.123
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Forwarded-Host: example.com:443
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Forwarded-Server: example.com
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Connection: close
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: sec-fetch-dest: document
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: sec-fetch-mode: navigate
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: sec-fetch-site: none
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: sec-fetch-user: ?1
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Cookie: [stripped]
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: [1B blob data]
```

where the URL is protocol agnostic and `X-Forwarded-Proto: https`.

And the response

```
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: 302  HTTP/1.0
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Set-Cookie: [stripped]; Path=/geoserver; HttpOnly
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 07:49:33 GMT
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Pragma: no-cache
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: Location: http://example.com/geoserver/web/
Feb 19 08:49:33 host startup.sh[733598]: [1B blob data]
```

with the non-https, full `Location` redirection. Between those logging lines I found nothing related to a redirection or protocol downgrade.

## Things I tried

Setting the **proxy base url** to `https://example.com/geoserver` in the service's environment, in `/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml` and in GeoServer's `global.xml`. Did not fix this and there is no full documentation about what this should actually do (I only found a suggestion that it would use that base URL in service response like WMS or WFS).

Comment: Setting the proxy URL to https should be enough, but I've never tried it with jetty as that's not designed for production use and it may not work in the same way as tomcat.

Comment: Cheers, will try! The URL should be "`https://example.com/geoserver`", not just verbatim "`https`", correct?

Comment: thats right - full URL

Comment: Sadly switching to Tomcat (and GeoServer 2.24.2) did not change this behaviour. `https://example.com/geoserver/web/` still redirects to `http://example.com/geoserver/web/?1` (non-https) as do any other requests under `/web/`.

Comment: do you have a trailing slash on the proxy url?

Comment: Same behaviour with or without. I managed to get it to work with Tomcat though (see answer). Not sure if what I did is overriding a GeoServer behaviour or if that was the fix I would have needed as equivalent in Jetty too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I did not manage to fix it with Jetty as server between GeoServer and the nginx reverse proxy, I found a solution when using Tomcat:

Adding `scheme="https" secure="true"` to the `Connector` in `/etc/tomcat/server.xml` made the redirections use `https` as desired.

I found this in https://serverfault.com/questions/742922/configure-tomcat-behind-reverseproxy

I doubt that this is the right and proper configuration but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest with example from the below sample nginix configuration.

`return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri` will permanently redirect port 80 to port 443. The listen 443 directive specifies that this server block will listen for incoming connections on port 443, which is the default port for HTTPS traffic. The ssl parameter indicates that SSL/TLS encryption should be used for this server block. There are additional configurations related to SSL/TLS certificates and encryption settings which in my case is generated from letsencrypt.

```
 server {
          listen 80;
          server_name example.com;
          return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        client_max_body_size 1060M;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

          
        location /geoserver {
            proxy_pass http://geoserver:8080/geoserver;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }    

        location /{
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

In your case I see IP address, make sure you have domain before generating the encryption from letsencrypt.

Comment: Thanks but that would be a workaround, not a fix. I want to stop GeoServer/Jetty from redirecting, not forcing re-redirections in the proxy in front of it. With this approach GeoServer would still make clients do unencrypted requests.